# Rails: How do you access model and controller data across views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partials

I am creating an app to vote on your favorite lunch, and I'm reusing code that I learned from a tutorial (railstutorial.org.) I have a relatively simply hierarchy within my data models, which look like this:

**Cuisine model:**

```
has_many :providers
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Cuisine has the following columns:

```
:id, :name
```

**Provider model:**

```
    belongs_to :cuisine
    has_many :lunches
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :cuisine, presence: true
```

which has the following attributes:

```
:id, :name, :cuisine_id
```

**Lunch model:**

```
belongs_to :provider
default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
validates :date, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Which has the following attributes:

```
:id, :date, :liked, :disliked, :provider_id, :lunchscore
```

A pretty straight forward inheritance model, to my untrained eye.  What I am looking to do is list out all the different lunches that are associated with a provider, and highlight their score.

**Provider Controller:**

```
def show
    @provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
    @lunches = @provider.lunches
    @cuisine = @provider.cuisine

  end
```

In my **Provider show.html.erb view**, I have the following basic code:

```
<div class="title"><%= @provider.name.upcase %> </div> <div class="cuisine"> <%= @cuisine.name %>  </div>

<div class="span8">
    <% if @provider.lunches.any? %>
    <h3> Total Lunches - (<%= @provider.lunches.count %>) </h3>
    <%= render @lunches %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I also have a partial in the **lunches** folder called _lunch.html.erb which contains the following:

```
<ul>
    <span class="date_list"> <%= lunch.date %> - <%= @provider.name %>  </span>
        <span class="timestamp">Created <%= time_ago_in_words(lunch.created_at) %> ago. </span> 
  </span>
</ul>
```

This outputs the following to the page:

Total Lunches - (1)
2015-01-24 - Sophies Created 2 days ago.

Whilst this works (and that's great) I'm scratching my head trying to understand the behavior.  Specifically:

1. Why put this partial in the *lunches* folder (as it is currently) instead of the provider folder? Does it have to be in the views/lunches folder?
2. Why is the render call written like an instance variable  `<%= render @lunches %>` vs. specifying a folder, e.g. `<%= render lunches/lunch %>`? Why doesn't the path need to be declared at all? how is rails transcribing @lunches into _lunch.html.erb?
3. Do I *need* to be rendering a partial in the lunches subfolder at all, or is there an easier way to access lunch data in a provider view?

Thanks in advance for likely a simple question.  My app is working, I'm just trying to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to render an active record object by it self, rails converts that object into a partial by calling `to_partial_path`, which is by default the `view/models/_model` path, you can test it by calling something like `Lunch.new.to_partial_path`

if you try render a single lunch: `render @lunch` it would be equivalent to

```
render partial: 'lunches/lunch', locals: {lunch: @lunch}
```

I didn't know it supported using a collection `render @lunches`, but since you said it works so i guess it does, in this condition the equivalent would be something like

```
render partial: 'lunches/lunch', collection: @lunches, as: :lunch
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - extremely helpful.  I might use the longer form equivalent just so I know what is happening.  Do I need to always render this in the lunches path, or could I "read" the lunch data from within the provider controller / view?

Comment: could you explain your question more